# White screen appears when running the application in android studio

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio

I/SurfaceView(19385): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{f938425 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(19385): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{f938425 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(19385): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{f938425 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(19385): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{f938425 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(19385): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{f938425 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(19385): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{f938425 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-600,976}

It just shows these codes. I hope for a solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.